# What effect does the “loading” weapon property have in practical terms?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, ranged-attack

What effect does the “loading” [weapon property](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/equipment#WeaponProperties) have in practical terms?

1. In the absence of the property, why would it be assumed that a PC could fire more than once per action (firing once would be one action)?
2. The scenario I’m picturing is where a PC has action, bonus action, and reaction on a turn.  It would seem that a PC could fire 3 times.

In essence, this property doesn’t seem to make any difference (at least that I can see).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## It limits PCs with the Extra Attack class feature

A 5th level Fighter (and many other classes) are able to make multiple attacks as part of their Attack Action. The Loading property prevents a character with Extra Attack from making multiple attacks with that weapon.

Comment: This would be rather overpowered if the Fighter could use a Heavy crossbow 4 times on his/her turn. 4 times 5.5 (H. crossbow) vs. 4 times 4.5 (Longbow). If you were allowed to ignore Loading, you could deal 22 damage avg. per turn as opposed to 18.

Comment: @TheCentaur I didn't mention it in my answer because it wasn't relevant, but the Crossbow Expert feat lets you do just that. :P

Comment: @Nesbitto yes it does, but it costs you a feat, for +1 average damage per attack. Feats in 5e are \_rare\_. The Sharpshooter feat, in comparison, allows you to deal +10 damage if you reduce your attack roll by 5.